# Is there a way to write an Azure Cosmos Db Query that allows me to see if a db record field that is a list is a subset of a provided array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a list of strings and my cosmos db records have a field that is also a list of strings. I need to write a cosmos db query that will see if the list of strings in the cosmos db record field is a subset of the list of strings I provided.

example

db record:

```json
{
   "name": "Jake",
   "ids": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

otherIds:  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I need a query that checks if db record ids is a subset of other ids.

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data illustrating what you mean by documents containing lists of strings, as well as expected results of your query. And then include what you’ve tried, errors, output issues, etc. as written, this is unfortunately unclear and too broad.

Comment: Ok, you've edited your question, but you still haven't shown what you've tried. That said: perhaps look at `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` to see if that helps you get closer to a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.